# How to partition a 1 TB drive for performance on a windows development machine?

Tags: windows, performance, partitioning, storage

I saw a similar question for linux, but nothing for windows.  I'm getting a new 1TB drive for my dev box @ work.  The OS will be Windows 7 Pro with 8GB of RAM and just the single 1TB drive.  Backups are not a concern, and I won't be storing large multimedia files.  I want the fastest possible performance for general windows usage and for compilation.  I will defrag nightly with a smart defragger liker perfectdisk.

Should I just go with a single partition, or is there some way I can lay things out for the best performance?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's a toss-up. If you need to do a lot of disk I/O activity, you'll really be better served with multiple disks on separate controllers.

For general use, I think that I would create an OS partition of 250G, and leave the rest in a second partition. However, since Windows 7 now let's you resize a partition (including OS partition), it's much less of an issue than it used to be.

Comment: +1  Agree that a partition won't help if there is a great deal of disk I/O. An eSATA drive as a second perhaps?